# Footer not 100% bottom crossbrowser

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, fullscreen, footer

This is my first question here, so bare in mind that we may have some issues with code.

But the thing is that i'm using a template (Cant remember what template atm) that is supposed to work in every browser but i cant get the code to the bottom.

URL TO SITE IN 1 Comment.

I'm pasting the HTML & CSS with Pastebin for you people that don't wanna see the page.

Please bare in mind that the CSS is rough and not clean, same with the HTML as the page is under development.

I searched here a couple of times without result, and couldn't get it going without messing up the whole page.

I can only test this live on Safari in Yosemite, and on Chrome Win 7.

[HTML](http://pastebin.com/ye5kFEmX) and 
[CSS](http://pastebin.com/6Trd9hYC)

I think myself that it have with the bottom images to do with.

FYI: I don't own any of the logos and this is a non profit entuisasm project for F1 Simracing.

Thank you and kind regards.

Comment: http://robinsjodin.se/F12009V2/

Comment: Do you want the footer to stretch to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Remove from `.footer_wrapper` `float`, `left`, `margin-left` and probably `width`. It can't show corretly in different resolutions (not browsers). Try to do it _normally_.

Comment: panther: Didn't help i'm aifraid.
luke: Yes

Comment: add to your css, overflow: visible;

Comment: still doesnt help. I found an solution but then the content  gets hidden behind. 

`footer {
display:                                table-row;
background:                             black;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
`

Comment: Can you a screenshot of actual output you are getting.

Comment: Alright, now i got the footer to stick to the bottom.
Here is an image [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/zfGEfj8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U have really messed your code a lot..!

Do these changes, it will work perfectly. 
**remove html,body {height:100%}**

```
/**** add CSS ***/
html {min-height: 100%;position: relative;}
body {margin-bottom: 288px;}/* height of footer */
footer {position:absolute;width:100%;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;}
```

delete that container tag from bottom of html page.

Comment: Alright, Take a look now, i'm so close now to a solution :)
http://www.robinsjodin.se/F12009V2/information.php

Comment: remove position relative from body tag in css on line no. 23

Comment: Happy2deepak: YOU'RE MY GENIUS! Thank you!

Comment: THANK YOU! 

Is there any good tool for cleaning upp messy CSS that doesnt mess up CSS?

Comment: there are many: search for CSS beautifier  (same for HTML or JS)

http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/
http://codebeautify.org/css-beautify-minify
http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Thank you for everything! :) Marked and done and css and html cleaned up perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got the footer to the absoulte bottom of the browser (Safari atm)

But the content gets hidden behind the footer, and thats no good.

Attaching image and code
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHZrM.jpg)  [CSS](http://pastebin.com/a02paDpj)

Im really sorry for the messy CSS, but i really appreciate all help!